Finding function for gradient field
I am probably just stuck with some stupidity in my brain but I cannot reason what is going wrong in this problem. I am doing multivariable calculus MIT course and I am also doing exercises from Stewart Calculus related chapters.
The problem is to check field to be conservative and if so find a potential function:
$$F(x,y) = (y^2cos(x)+cos(y))i+(2ysin(x)-xsin(y))j$$
Field is indeed conservative and f should be $$y^2sin(x)+xcos(y)+C$$
But I was trying one of the methods from lecture - to take line integral from (0,0) to (x1,y1)
$$\int_C  (y^2cos(x)+cos(y))dx+(2ysin(x)-xsin(y))dy $$
First following path from (0,0) to (x1,0) and then from (x1,0) to (x1,y1). Link to part of the lecture
When I am trying to take the first line integral $$\int_0^{x_1} 0*cosx+cos0 \, dx = x_1$$
Then by integrating second part $$\int_0^{y_1} (2ysin(x_1)-x_1sin(y))\,dy=y_1^2sin(x_1)+x_1cos(y_1)$$
Adding two integrals and replacing x1,y1 to x,y (as it was made to avoid confusion during integration). I got $$y^2sin(x)+xcos(y)+x+C$$
So I got additional "x" as a component of resulting function. Where I did wrong?
Update:
Many thanks to @FedericoFallucca. I made a mistake in calculation of the second line integral, I should get -x1 at evaluating it at y=0. So it would cancel x1 I got from the first one and overall result will be correct.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The problem is the second integral, you have to subtract also the primitive function evaluated at $0$, so that you will obtain a -x_1. At this point, when you add the integrals, you still obtain the same potential. Note that, since you started at (0,0), then you will obtain only one of the infinite potential functions, that one for which f(0,0)=0.

@FedericoFallucca thanks a lot man! I could not figure out when I made mistake.
